# How to create MX Excel file from DataTable?

Tags: datatable, export-to-excel

I need to create MS Excel file from DataTable in ASP.NET application. I don't need "SaveAs" dialog. Just create a file and save them to some folder.

I've searched the internet and found some examples how to do that by using Microsoft Excel Interop library. But, I can't use Excel Interop library. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XLReport](http://www.xlreport.com); it allows you to connect to your database tables and import the underlying data into Excel; you can also create a real time - live - connect Excel sheet where you only need to hit the Refresh button in order to retrieve the most recent data.